# Unit test cases for cookies in angular 15

Tags: angular, unit-testing, code-coverage, angular15

I have written test cases for one my component. It's covering the whole function but throws these errors:

```
  Disconnected , because no message in 30000 ms.
```

OR

```
 Some of your tests did a full page
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private cookieService:CookieService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  logout(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    let cookie:any = this.cookieService.getAll();
    Object.keys(cookie)?.forEach((res:any) => {
        this.cookieService.delete(res, '/', '', true, 'None');
        document.cookie = `${res}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;`;
    });
    window.location.href ='https://demo.demopreview.com/login/login.htm';
   }
}
```

**header.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
  let cookieService: CookieService;

  const mockWindow = { location: { href: '' } };
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HeaderComponent],
      imports:[HttpClientModule],
      providers: [
        CookieService,
        { provide: 'Window', useValue: mockWindow }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    cookieService = TestBed.inject(CookieService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    document.cookie.split(";").forEach((c) => {
      document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/");
    });
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call cookieService.delete for each cookie', () => {
    spyOn(cookieService, 'getAll').and.returnValue({ 'testCookie1': 'value1', 'testCookie2': 'value2' });
    spyOn(cookieService, 'delete');
    component.logout();
    expect(cookieService.delete).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testCookie1', '/', '', true, 'None');
    expect(cookieService.delete).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testCookie2', '/', '', true, 'None');
  });

});
```

Its' not related any version issues. Beacause if I remove this test case every test cases passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must test code that involves direct manipulation of `window.location.href`, you may need to adopt a different strategy

In your AppModule, provide the window object as a value. This will allow you to inject it wherever needed.

**app.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({        
  providers: [
    { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In your HeaderComponent, inject the window object using the 'Window' token. instead of referencing window object directly

**header.component.ts**

```
  constructor(private cookieService:CookieService,@Inject('Window') private window: Window ) {}
  
  logout(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    let cookie:any = this.cookieService.getAll();
    Object.keys(cookie)?.forEach((res:any) => {
        this.cookieService.delete(res, '/', '', true, 'None');
        document.cookie = `${res}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;`;
    });
    this.window.location.href ='https://demo.demopreview.com/login/login.htm';
   }
```

The logout method is asynchronous. To handle asynchronous code in Angular tests, you should use the async and fakeAsync functions provided by Angular testing utilities.

**header.component.spec.ts**

```
 it('should call cookieService.delete for each cookie', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(cookieService, 'getAll').and.returnValue({ 'testCookie1': 'value1', 'testCookie2': 'value2' });
    spyOn(cookieService, 'delete');
   
    component.logout();

    
    // Simulate the passage of time until all asynchronous activities complete
     tick();

    expect(cookieService.delete).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testCookie1', '/', '', true, 'None');
    expect(cookieService.delete).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testCookie2', '/', '', true, 'None');

  }));
```

Comment: Still getting this error >> 13 02 2024 11:17:35.639:WARN [Chrome Headless 114.0.5735.133 (Windows 10)]: Disconnected (0 times) , because no message Chrome Headless 114.0.5735.133 (Windows 10) ERROR
  Disconnected , because no message in 30000 ms.

Comment: Have you added this  on providers array inapp.module  { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }?

Comment: Header componet also changed as per suggestion?

Comment: Yes I changed as per the suggestion

Comment: My bad - I missed **this.window.location.href** .Thanks @chellapan